# Magento2: HTML tag is not working in custom email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, frontend-error

HTML tag is not working in the custom email template.

**HTML file**

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

{{trans "Csr Name: %name" name=$data.csrname}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.csremail}}
{{trans "Product Name: %pname" pname=$data.productname}}
{{trans "Sku: %sku" sku=$data.productsku}}
{{trans "Product Price: %pprice" pprice=$data.productprice}}
{{trans "Authorized Price: %authorizedprice" authorizedprice=$data.authorizedprice}}
{{trans "Approve Price: %approveprice" approveprice=$data.approveprice}}
{{trans 'Please <a href="%approveurl">Click here</a> for approve price.' approveurl=$data.approvelink|raw}}

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**Genrated email template**

[image]

Comment: Add the **href** tag outside the trans brackets <a href="{{trans

Comment: I have tried. It is not working @YlgenGuxholli

Comment: The issue is resolved. I have changed type ***text to html*** in email_templates.xml.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this file:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_update.html

```
<p>{{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}</p>


   {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}
```

Probably is something related to transport :

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Sender/EmailSender.php

Comment: The issue is resolved. I have changed type ***text to html*** in email_templates.xml